# How does printing a fixeddocument work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing, document

I read somewhere that regardless of the resolution of the printer, the page will print exactly the same when printing a fixeddocument.

Say you had a document that printed on one page on printer x, and suppose printer y has a higher resolution than printer x...

when you print the document on printer y, would it auto size to fill the whole page? or would it not fill?

thanks

EDIT**

I read about fixed documents here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx

more specifically, this paragraph:

> Fixed documents are intended for applications that require a precise "what you see is what you get" (WYSIWYG) presentation, independent of the display or printer hardware used. Typical uses for fixed documents include desktop publishing, word processing, and form layout, where adherence to the original page design is critical. As part of its layout, a fixed document maintains the precise positional placement of content elements independent of the display or print device in use. For example, a fixed document page viewed on 96 dpi display will appear exactly the same when it is output to a 600 dpi laser printer as when it is output to a 4800 dpi phototypesetter. The page layout remains the same in all cases, while the document quality maximizes to the capabilities of each device.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: i added the link and text above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All else being equal, the fixed document will print at the same physical size on both printers, regardless of the printer resolution. So, if the fixed document covers an entire sheet of 8.5 x 11 paper on printer x, it will still cover an entire sheet of 8.5 x 11 paper when printed on printer y.